# Common method call on Error in amplify.request

Tags: amplifyjs

In My Application I am using amplify.js to call the data API.
On Response from the API I want to check if the response is 403 Forbidden and redirect the user to Login page. 
My Problem is I have about 50 different API call and I want to hadle it in one place.
Is there any way in amplify.js to handle the error is single place?

Comment: Did you come up with a solution??